# Size for webcam in Flash?

Tags: resize, flash, size, webcam

I've just an SWF object to display the users webcam, however it won't let me make the webcam smaller than 320 x 240.
Is this the lowest size I can go?

Just for any reference if needed:

```
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.media.Video;

var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
var vid:Video = new Video(320, 240);

camera.setQuality(100, 300);

vid.smoothing = true;
vid.attachCamera(camera);
vid.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - vid.width/2;
vid.y = 0;

addChild(vid);
```

Thanks.

Comment: I've tried changing it to 160 x 120 but it just shows blank/whiteness.

Comment: that is not scaling it vid.scaleX vid.scaleY

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

`camera.setMode(videoWidth, videoHeight, video fps, favor area);`

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6